# Logging NodeJS application in production

Tags: node.js, logging, error-logging, console.log

I am a beginner to Node. Would anyone tell how to handle errors in NodeJS? Also how to define node server to write its logs to a default file instead writing to console.

Comment: You can use winston logging..

Comment: I want to use bunyan logging. Can we configure a single file where bunyan will save all its logs...like we have in case of jetty server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) is a good npm package for logging data to files or to a database (Mongo).

Comment: winston is for logging.Anyways i am using bunyan logging. I would like to know how to handle errors